# Write a function named index_of_smallest that takes a list of integers

Tags: python

Write a function named `index_of_smallest` that takes a list of integers as an argument and returns the index of the smallest element in the list. The function should return `-1` if the list is an empty list.

```
def index_of_smallest(list1):
    if len(list1) == 0:
        return -1
    smallest_value = list1[0]
    smallest_index = 0
    for i in range(len(list1)):
        if smallest_value >:
            smallest_index +=1
    return smallest_value    

print(index_of_smallest([51, 65, 66, 80, 10, 55]))
#output: 4
print(index_of_smallest([]))
#output: -1
```

Comment: Whats your question?

Comment: return list1.index(min(list1)) if you’re looking for smallest number in list and index

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
def index_of_smallest(lista):
  if len(lista) == 0: return -1
  return sorted(enumerate(lista),key=lambda x:x[1])[0][0]
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
def index_of_smallest(list_a):
    return list_a.index(min(list_a)) if list_a else -1
```